# Why does this Actionscript code work on Chrome but not FF and IE?

Tags: actionscript, cross-browser

Why does this example, (from adobe.com) work in Chrome, but not in FF and IE?:

does not work = I can see the permission window, but when I click 'allow' all I see is a blank white screen.

http://wonderfl.net/c/7624

or see code below:

```
// frame action
import flash.media.Microphone;
import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.display.Graphics;
var nWidth:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var nCenter:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;
var nScale:Number = 100;
var myGraphics:Graphics = graphics;
var my_mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
my_mic.rate = 22;
my_mic.gain = 100;
my_mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, drawSampleData);
function drawSampleData(eventObject:SampleDataEvent):void 
{
   var myData:ByteArray = eventObject.data;
   myGraphics.clear();
   myGraphics.lineStyle(0, 0x000000);
   myGraphics.moveTo(0, nCenter);
   var nPitch:Number = nWidth / myData.length;
   while (myData.bytesAvailable > 0) 
    {
   var nX:Number = myData.position * nPitch;
   var nY:Number = myData.readFloat() * nScale + nCenter;
   myGraphics.lineTo(nX, nY);
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: it does work in one of my computers' FF, but not in its IE. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the example in the link you included and it did not work in any of my browsers, Chrome included.

The source code in the link you have included shows most of your code (including a few imports) nested inside a function called FlashTest, in my experience I cannot understand why this would even run in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks. Imports were a mistake. New version - this: http://wonderfl.net/c/lNa1 does work on Chrome but not on FF and IE (for me). Do you know why?

Comment: Or maybe I should ask: what is it that I'm doing wrong? Why do you think it wouldn't run? Thanks for your help.